# Use np.where on a Mixed data type column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column with data type 'o'. It has numbers, as well String. For example:

| Days |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 15 |
| 7 |
| No Sales Data available |
| 9 |

I am trying to make a separate column using np.where, where I have written the code as

```
np.where(df['Days']=='No Sales Data available','No Sales',np.where(df['Days']<=10, 'Less than 10 days Sales','More than 10 Days Sales'))
```

Naturally, the code is giving problems due to mixed data types. Any idea how to get around such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your statement in this way which will preserve the data type of your 'Days' column.

```
df['new'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['Days'],errors='coerce').isna(),'No Sale',
             np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['Days'],errors='coerce') <= 10,
               'Less than 10 days Sales','More than 10 Days Sales'))
print(df)
                      Days                      new
0                        5  Less than 10 days Sales
1                       10  Less than 10 days Sales
2                       15  More than 10 Days Sales
3                        7  Less than 10 days Sales
4  No Sales Data available                  No Sale
5                        9  Less than 10 days Sales
```

---

If you don't mind changing the type of your column, you could first convert to numeric and following a similar logic:

```
df['Days'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Days'],errors='coerce')
df['new'] = np.where(df['Days'].isna(),'No Sale',np.where(df['Days']<=10,'Less than 10 days Sales','More than 10 Days Sales'))

print(df)

   Days                      new
0   5.0  Less than 10 days Sales
1  10.0  Less than 10 days Sales
2  15.0  More than 10 Days Sales
3   7.0  Less than 10 days Sales
4   NaN                  No Sale
5   9.0  Less than 10 days Sales
```